# How can I plot output from a function which returns multiple values in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, physics, multipleoutputs

### Short intro

I'm calculating and plotting spectral energy of planets orbiting pulsar from given data.

I have previously ordered all data in a list *variations* with dimensions [172, 2] (172 rows and 2 columns).

Firstly, I have to calculate parameters of a presupposed model and spectral energy accordingly (from those very parameters).

To do that, I defined a function under which I defined the presupposed model and *find_fit* function which takes the model and variations data.

### Code

```
 var('a, b, t')

def spectrum(omega):

    model = a*sin(omega*t) + b*cos(omega*t)
    fit = find_fit(variations, model, parameters= [a, b], variables = [t], solution_dict = True)
    sp_en = ((fit[a])**2 + (fit[b])**2)/2

    return fit[a], fit[b], sp_en
```

Then I call the function and print values:

```
c, v, energy = spectrum(20)   #enter arbitray angular frequency here
print "Values for the given angular frequency : \n \n a = %f, b = %f, spectral_energy = %f " % (c, v, energy)
```

---

Now I have to plot  ***only*** ***sp_en*** output.

### "Semi-solution"

It is easy to that if a *spectrum* function return ***only sp_en***. It is sufficient than to write:

```
var('t')
plot(spectrum(t), (t, 1, 100))
```

Which returns:
[energy-omega plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8QpQ.png)

---

The question than is: how do I plot this function if I want to print all three outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use indexing on the return value from spectrum:

```
plot(spectrum(t)[2], (t, 1, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know I can use indexing this way. Indexing did plot only energy. But still something was missing. This is the correct solution. `plot(lambda t:spectrum(t)[2], (t, 1, 100))`

Answer (score 0):

Just call the plot function with only the `energy` variable

```
omega=10
c, v, energy = spectrum(omega)   #enter arbitray angular frequency here
print "Values for the given angular frequency : \n \n a = %f, b = %f, spectral_energy = %f " % (c, v, energy)
```

`plot(energy, (omega, 1, 100)`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This line doesn't work. I get the error: "Variable omega is not defined".

Comment: I just reused it from your func. definition, edited so it works now.